# Cannot get remote video displayed

Tags: javascript, video, webrtc

I have implemented two webrtc clients (peers) and a simple signaling server. Three elements are in local. Despite the get media, the offer/answer methods between peers and the signaling server seems working, I am only able to display local videos in both peers (both in different browser tabs)

Here is the SDP that the offerer sends to the other peer

```
v=0
o=- 1118386230690454721 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=-
t=0 0
a=msid-semantic: WMS
```

The other peer answers with similar SDP but other session id.

```
localVideo = document.querySelector('#localVideo');
    remoteVideo = document.querySelector('#remoteVideo');

    socket = io.connect("http://localhost:3000");

    pc = new RTCPeerConnection(null);
    var constraints = {video: true, audio: true};
    getUserMedia(constraints, handleUserMedia, handleUserMediaError);

    pc.onaddstream = handleRemoteStreamAdded;
    pc.onremovestream = handleRemoteStreamRemoved;
    pc.onicecandidate = handleIceCandidate;

    var lspd;

    pc.createOffer().then(function(offer) {
        lspd = offer;
        return pc.setLocalDescription(offer);
    }).then(function() {
        var offerData = {
            sdp: lspd,
            customerName: "name",
            room: room
        }
        socket.emit('offer', offerData);

        }).catch(function(reason) {
            console.log("Error on createOffer: " + reason);
        });

    socket.on('answering', function (msg){
        pc.setRemoteDescription(msg);
    });

   function handleRemoteStreamAdded(event) {
        remoteVideo.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(event.stream);
        remoteStream = event.stream;
    }

    function handleUserMedia(stream) {
        localVideo.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
        localStream = stream;
        pc.addStream(stream);
    }
```

The onaddstream is never added in both peers and I never can see remote video. Moreover it seems that the SDP is not complete.

Any ideas on what could I try or debug in order to reach communication between peers?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are calling createOffer before adding the stream to the peerconnection. You need to move your code that calls createOffer (and everything after that) to the handleUserMedia function.

Comment: Thanks Philipp for your fast answer :)